# hibernate JPA error : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am learning to write spring web application and i get this error:
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [SELECT u FROM users u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.password = :password]]
can someone help me fix this table not mapped issue:

[my JPA configuration class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCqeN.png)

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb  = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
    emfb.afterPropertiesSet();

    return emfb.getObject();
 }

 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
   ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schoolDB");
   ds.setUsername("postgres");
   ds.setPassword("******");
   return ds;
 }
 }
```

[my model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZweZe.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;
@Column(name="username")
private String username;
@Column(name="password")
private String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
```

[repository configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q1WA.png)

```
@Repository  
public class UserRepository {

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myschool")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRepository.class);

public User checkUser(String username, String password) {
    logger.info("********** User Repository ********");
    try {  
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<User> typedQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM users u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.password = :password", User.class);
        typedQuery.setParameter("username", username);
        typedQuery.setParameter("password", password);

        return typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        logger.info("********** User Repository Exception ********");
        return null;
    }
}
   
}
```

[my persistence.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDdrg.png)

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="myschool">

   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

   <properties>
    
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schoolDB" />
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
       <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******" />

       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
       <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
       
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/> <!-- update -->
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->

   </properties>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please post you code (correctly formatted as code) into your question, we don't like to be directed away from our favorite site via external links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not
> mapped

`createQuery` used to create JPQL. In JPQL, you should use the name of the `Entity` class instead of the name of the table. So use `User` instead of `users` in query

```
em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username AND u.password = :password", User.class);
```